# Plotly library is plotting blank space while seaborn is plotting correctly

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, seaborn, histogram

[image]

**My code**

```
import seaborn as sns
import plotly.express as px

sns.histplot(df_user_test_session_question_accuracy, x="QuestionAccuracy")


df = df_user_test_session_question_accuracy
fig = px.histogram(df, x="QuestionAccuracy",
                   title='Histogram of QuestionAccuracy ',
                   opacity=0.8,
                   log_y=True, # represent bars with log scale
                   color_discrete_sequence=['indianred'] # color of histogram bars
                   )
fig.show()
```

Here I am running both seaborn and plotly plot in a separate kernel , seaborn is plotting expected plots but plotly just giving a large blank space with no plots, What is the error behind it
I want to use plotly for its interactiveness, any help is appreciated

Comment: Why don't you present the data for reproducibility? As it is, no one has any incentive to respond.

Comment: added the screenshot

Comment: I'll share the link to [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1dSW9HvZNmtViEeRSCkxTdy2rsuxUe_Yp?usp=sharing). I will share the Colab link with you, and will remove Colab once you have verified it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seaborn uses `np.histogram()`.  If you want same calculation framework,  use it and effectively plot using `go.Scatter()`

```
import seaborn as sns
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_user_test_session_question_accuracy = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "QuestionId": np.arange(0, 18000),
        "QuestionAccuracy": np.random.uniform(0, 1, 18000),
    }
)

# use consistent number of bins across various plots...
BINS = 25

sns.histplot(df_user_test_session_question_accuracy, x="QuestionAccuracy", bins=BINS)


df = df_user_test_session_question_accuracy
fig = px.histogram(
    df,
    x="QuestionAccuracy",
    title="Histogram of QuestionAccuracy ",
    opacity=0.8,
    nbins=BINS,
    log_y=True,  # represent bars with log scale
    color_discrete_sequence=["indianred"],  # color of histogram bars
)
fig.show()

# use same mechanisim as seaborn to calculate histrogram bins
y, x = np.histogram(df["QuestionAccuracy"], bins=BINS)
x = np.round(x, 2)
go.Figure(go.Scatter(y=y, line_shape="hvh", fill="tozeroy")).update_xaxes(
    tickmode="array",
    tickvals=np.linspace(0, len(x), 6),
    ticktext=np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 6),
).show()
```